# Как картинку централизовать вертикально внутри div?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Нужно картинку любых размеров заставить сидеть в центре `div` с заданным размером.

Пытаюсь сделать так ([CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QyQvXe))

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="cell">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/logo.png" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.cell {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #E9E8E2;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
}
```

Результат в разных браузерах удивляет.

IE 11:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

FF 43

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Safari 7.1

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И лишь Chrome даёт желаемый результат

Chrome 47

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как кроссбраузерно централизовать картинку (любого размера) внутри `div`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

такой вариант подойдет?

```css
.block {
  display: table;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #E9E8E2;  
}
.block-cell{
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.block-cell img{  
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="block">
       <div class="block-cell"> <img class="img-responsive" src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/logo.png" alt="">
         </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Вы указали размер блока в 100x100, но граница выглядит прямоугольной. У вас это выглядит квадратно?

Comment: @LEQADA поправил

Comment: В FF 43 всё равно прямоугольник.

Comment: width 100% для img необходимо еще задать

Comment: Теперь выглядит отлично :). Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

http://caniuse.com/#search=flex

```css
html, body{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://ipic.su/img/img7/fs/100x100falloutav-vb.1453536215.gif">
</div>
```

Comment: У вас картинка выйдет за границы блока, если её размер превосходит размер блока.

Comment: Исправил, теперь не выйдет.

Comment: На IE11 выглядит так http://i.stack.imgur.com/5dWoe.png А на Safari 7.1 выглядит так же, как и в вопросе.

Answer (score -1):

Пример:

```css
.col-md-12 {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid #E9E8E2;
  position: relative;
}
.cell {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="cell">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/logo.png" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Но у тебя тут бутстрап я виду, поэтому просто добавь клас .text-center

Comment: `text-center` централизует во горизонтали. Всего лишь `text-align:center`. Как вы предлагаете это применять?

Comment: А чем не устраивает вариант выше ?

Comment: Проблема в том, что в вашем примере, если картинку сделать размером в блок, то он будет посередине. Это не то, чего я пытаюсь добиться. Мне нужно, чтобы конкретно в данном блоке картинки любого размера централизовались вертикально. Если картинка сама подходит по размерам бока, то она будет выглядеть во весь блок. Как если бы в примере из вопроса вместо логотипа сайта подставить картинку 100x100 и посмотреть на это в Chrome

Comment: Спасибо вам за попытку) Минус, кстати, не мой.